# Show that there exist a prime divisor of $\sigma{((2^k)!)}$ which is greater than $2^k$

Tags: number-theory

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Show that there exists a prime divisor of $\sigma{((2^k)!)}$ which is greater than $2^k$, where $\sigma{(n)}$ is the sum-of-divisors function.

Comment: What if $k=1$ ?

Comment: $3\mid \sigma((2^1)!)$ and $3>2^1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put together the following pieces:

- $\sigma$ is multiplicative in the sense that if $\gcd(m,n)=1$ the $\sigma(mn)=\sigma(m)\sigma(n)$. This is just a consequence of unique factorization of integers.
- The highest power of two that is a factor of $(2^k)!$ is $2^{2^k-1}$. You have probably seen the formula for the $p$-adic value of a factorial. Can be found [on our site as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141196/11619).
- Thus $\sigma(2^{2^k-1})=2^{2^k}-1=(2^{2^{k-1}}-1)(2^{2^{k-1}}+1)$ is a factor of $\sigma((2^k)!).$
- From the context of prime factors of Fermat numbers we know that all the prime factors $p$ of $2^{2^{k-1}}+1$ satisfy the congruence $p\equiv1\pmod{2^{k+1}}$ if $k\ge3$, and $p\equiv1\pmod{2^k}$ for all $k$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83938/11619) for a local explanation. Actually [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91413/11619) suffices here.

Comment: How to get here? Don't you think that because we were asked to look at $(2^k)!$ the prime factor $2$ may become important? Let's see, where that takes us!

Comment: Nice answer!+1 Thank you

Comment: if we find this $\sigma{((3^k)!)}$  prime divisor is greater than $3^{k}?$