# To prove that the nth fermat number for $n \lt 4$ is prime, does the proof involve

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fermat-numbers

simply plugging $0,1,2,3$, and $4$ into $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ and then observing that the results are prime. I can't think of any other way to 'prove' it, but the method I have proposed is a verification and not a proof.

Comment: What is missing from a verification to be a proof? Nothing.

Comment: Those are small enough numbers to be verified by brute force. When $n=4$ you may want to use [this result](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/91413/11619) to narrow down the set of candidate factors. At least if you use paper and pencil.

Comment: For primality testing you don't need to test $4$ as a divisor, but you do need to check $3$ and $5$.

Comment: If you can plug in all cases in a proof that is valid.  If you don't feel comfortable calling it a proof, that's not your fault.  It's the text's fault for calling it a proof.

Comment: You can narrow the search considerably.  if $p$ divides $F_n$ then $2^{2^n}\equiv -1\pmod p$ so $2$ has order $2^{n+1}$ $\pmod p$.  That implies that $2^{n+1}$ divides $p-1$.   Thus, to try to factor $F_5$ say you only need to consider prime factors of the form $64k+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Listing all possibilities and showing them to all be prime is a perfectly valid proof, provided you prove all those numbers are prime.  But it may not be what the asker is looking for.

Comment: So in the case of n=3, I get $F_n=257$. Is there some formal method of proving it is prime?

Comment: You need only attempt to divide by every integer up to the square root of $257$ and prove it does not divide by any. Clearly it's not even so no need to divide by any multiple of $2$. Also, since its digits don't add up to a multiple of $3$, there's no need to divide by any multiple of 3. Clearly not a muiltiple of $5$ as it doesn't end in a $5$ or $0$ so you only need to show it doesn't divide by 7,11 and 13. 250 doesn't divide by 7, so that's out. 253 is divisible by 11, so 11's out and 13 times 20 is 260 so that's out. Therefore it's prime.

Comment: @anna_xox Testing whether it's divisible by any prime $\leq 16$. There are six of them. That should take less than a minute by hand if you know how to check some of them without actually dividing (simple tricks exist for checking divisibility by $2,3,5,7$ and $11$ that I know of)

Comment: Again: Brute force. Realise if it's not prime it will have a factor less than it's square root, and then try all the possibilities.

Comment: 257 is small enough that simply stating "257 is prime" is fine.  If the reader has doubt the *reader* can verify it on his own damn time.

Comment: @fleablood my 5 year old daughter has no knowledge of how to verify it in her own time. Maths Stack Exchange is for mathematicians of *all* levels.

Comment: Does your daughter have any way to verify that if $n = 3$ that $2^{2^n} + 1 = 257$?  If we are asked to prove $2^{2^n} + 1$ is prime for n < 4;n natural including 0, it is enough to point out $2^{2^0} + 1 = 3$; $2^{2^1} + 1 = 5;$ and $2^{2^3} + 1 = 257$ and claim they are all prime.  We don't need to show that $b^0 = 1$ for $b \ne 0$ so $2^0 = 1$ and $b^1 = b$ for all $b$ so $2^{2^0} = 2$ and because $2 + 1 = 3$ and as $2^{2^0} = 2$  we can conclude $2^{2^0} + 1 = 3$ and 3 is prime because numbe can have a divisor larger than itself and the numbers lower than 3 or 0, and 1 and 2 and 3, and z..

Comment: @fleablood that proves you're good at maths, not that you're right about the reader verifying it in their own damn time.

Comment: A student is asked to prove that $2^{2^n} +1$ is prime for 0 $\le$ n < 4. It suffices for the student to simply list the values for $n = 0, 1,2,3,4.$n=0$ yields $2^{2^0} + 1 = 3$, $n = 1 $ yields $2^{2^1} + 1 = 5$.$n = 2 $ yields $2^{2^2}+1=2^4 + 1 = 17$ and $n= 3$ yields $2^{2^3} + 1 = 2^8+1 = 257$. The student can claim those are all prime numbers. It seem utterly picayune and petty (not to mention snide) and irrelevent to the level of the class, to expect the student to need to prove those are prime.  Presumably the audience is on the same and can either accept it or verify for themselves.

Comment: @fleablood bowing out.