# There is no Fermat number that is divisible by $97$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Because $97$ is a prime number of the form $3.2^n+1$, The order of $2$ modulo $97$ is either $3$, $2^k$ or $3\cdot2^k$ for some $0\le k\le n$.

Since $2^{2^k}-1=F_0F_1F_2\cdots F_{k-1}$,The order of $2$ modulo $97$ is not divisible by $3$ if and only if $97$ divides a Fermat number $F_k$ with $0\le k\le n-1$.
Now order of $2$ modulo $97$ is $48$, so there is no Fermat number $F_k$ with $0\le k\le n-1$ that is divisible by $97$. but I don't how obtain this result for$k\ge n$?

Comment: Hint: if $97 \mid 2^s + 1$, then $2^{2s} \equiv 1 \pmod{97}$.

Comment: Also, from this(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83938/a-theorem-about-prime-divisors-of-generalized-fermat-numbers), $$k\cdot2^{n+2}+1=97\implies n\le3$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a small thing you're overlooking. We have that $97\mid 2^e-1$ if and only if $\mbox{ord}_{97}(2)\mid e$.
If $97\mid F_k$, then $97\mid2^{2^{k+1}}-1$, thus...