# Let $p$ be a prime divisor of the Fermat number $F_n = 2^{2^ n} + 1$. Prove that $p$ must have the form $2^{n+1}k + 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fermat-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime divisor of the Fermat number $F_n = 2^{2^n} + 1$. Prove that $p$ must have the form $2^{n+1}k + 1$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $1k$?  $\space \space$

Comment: (2^(n+1))*k + 1

Comment: Or, possibly [a better duplicate target](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83938/11619).

Answer (score 1):

This is not very hard.

From Fermat's little theorem, $$p\mid 2^{p-1} -1,$$
also
$$p\mid 2^{2^n} + 1 \mid 2^{2^{n+1}} -1,$$
so $$p \mid \gcd(2^{p-1} -1, 2^{2^{n+1}}-1) = 2^{\gcd(p-1,\, 2^{n+1})}-1.$$

On the other hand, $$\gcd(p-1, 2^{n+1})=2^m$$ for some positive integer $m$ (as $p$ is odd). If $m<n+1$, then $$p\mid 2^{2^m}-1 \mid 2^{2^n} -1= F_n -2,$$ which is impossible. So $m=n+1$, and $2^{n+1} \mid p-1$.

Comment: Can you prove in fact $2^{n+2}|p-1$?

Comment: When n =1, we have p=2^(n+1)+1. I will think about cases n >=2.

Comment: We have that for $n=0$ as well as $n=1$.  For $n\ge2$, I thought of it related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3691565/show-that-2p-1-2-equiv-1-mathrmmod-p)

Comment: You are right. I was thinking around these lines. Don’t quite remember though.